# Hybris sort parameter in Solr

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

A weird problem is occurring.In my project,in lower environments everything seems fine,but in the higher environment(production),a sort parameter is getting appended to the Solr query when I search for a specific text,of the form:

```
                    &sort=score+asc,age_int+asc
```

where age is an attribute defined in items.xml.How do I debug this issue as I cannot find anything in SolrSort field also in backoffice,and also since this issue only occurs in production?

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually seeing this sort parameter appearing in the query URL string, then it originates from outside of Solr. I would check whatever client you are using to talk to Solr.

If you are seeing it in the Solr query, but it did not come from outside of Solr as an explicit parameter, it may be defined in solrconfig.xml, overlayconfig.json or params.json (last two for more recent versions of Solr). It is possible your production has those files and your development/QA do not.